# jQuery .listview('refresh') doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm facing problems using ('refresh'). I have dis **listview**

```
<div id="DetallePedidoRegistros" class="ui-collapsible-set" data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-mini="true">
    <div class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false"><h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading"><a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-mini ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-top" href="#" data-theme="a" data-icon="plus" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperEls="span" data-iconpos="left" data-mini="true"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top"><span class="ui-btn-text">Datos del Pedido<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to collapse contents</span></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-minus">&nbsp;</span></span></a></h3><div aria-hidden="false" class="ui-collapsible-content ui-corner-bottom">

        Abierto por Model.StrUsuarioGenera<br>
        A las Model.DatFechaDocumento<br>    
        Mesa: Model.IntIdMesa
    </div></div>        
</div>
```

Later i append elements using post

```
function actualizarDetallePedido(tcLink) {
   $.post(tcLink,
      function (detallepedido) {
        var id = $(detallepedido).attr('id');
        $("#DetalleDocumento").append(detallepedido);
        $("#DetalleDocumento").listview();
        $(this).listview('refresh');
     }
   );
}
```

It shows properly the items but as HTML code, it doesn´t show as jquerymobile objetect, What is the propper way to refresh it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidentally found the answer, I was trying to refresh and add this line of code

```
function actualizarDetallePedido(tcLink) {
  $.post(tcLink,
    function (detallepedido) {
        var id = $(detallepedido).attr('id');
        $("#DetalleDocumento").append(detallepedido);
        $('#' + id).collapsible(); //This line initializes  the object and don't need to refresh it 
    }
  );
}
```